# Maven assembly : Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I try to import a maven assembly dependency on a project, like describe on this page : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html

So, on the project A, I've created an assembly called abc-resources which is a jar file containing some txt files.
My goal is to import this jar into another project (like any other maven dependency).

So, in my new project, I've created a pom.xml with this code :

```
<build>
       ...
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mycompany.group.id</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myartifactid</artifactId>
                        <version>LATEST</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- This is where we use our shared assembly descriptor -->
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>abc-resources</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But I always receive an error :

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0:single (make-assembly) on project myNewProject: Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID 'abc-resources' not found -> [Help 1]
I tried with src/main/assembly/abc-resources, src/main/assembly/abc-resources.xml, ...
(abc-resources.xml is the filename used to create the assembly on the project A (in a path src/main/assembly).
Do you know what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Tigrou

Comment: Can you check that `mycompany.group.id:myartifactid:LATEST` indeed contains the `abc-resources` as you expect (open the jar in the target directory of that module with WinRAR or something and check)

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for your reply. I've checked on the jar and the files are indeed included in the artifactory.